# The argument type 'TextStyle' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextStyle?'. While calling a function that returns TextStyle

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have created a function called `getRegularStyle` that returns a `TextStyle`. And when I want to use it to **change** the `appBar` `titleTextStyle` it gives the following error:
**`The argument type 'TextStyle' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextStyle?'.`**
Here is my **Function**:

```
TextStyle _getTextStyle(double fontSize, String fontFamily, FontWeight fontWeight, Color color){
  return TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, fontFamily: fontFamily, fontWeight: fontWeight, color: color);
}
//Regular Style
TextStyle getRegularStyle({double fontSize = 12, required Color color}){
  return _getTextStyle(fontSize, FontConstants.fontFamily, FontWeightManager.regular, color);
}
```

Here is where I call the function to change the **titleTextStyle** of the **appBar**:

```
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    centerTitle: true,
    color: ColorManager.primary,
    elevation: AppSize.s4,
    shadowColor: ColorManager.primaryWithOpacity70,
    **titleTextStyle: getRegularStyle(color: ColorManager.white, fontSize: FontSize.s16),**
),
```

The **Bolded** line of code provides the error.

I even made the function nullable to solve the problem but it provided another error which in my case I thought it can't be the solution.

Comment: I replaced your custom items (`elevation: AppSize.s4` => `elevation: 4.0`, `color: ColorManager.white` => `Colors.white`, etc.) and am unable to reproduce.

Comment: Maybe you're not importing the same library in both files, if that's the case, TextStyle is different for each file

Comment: @LuisUtrera Sorry what did you mean?

Comment: @offworldwelcome I tried that, but it didn't solve my problem yet. Nothing changes.

Comment: @offworldwelcome I think you missed my error. The error is not there, it's when I call the function **getRegularStyle**.

Comment: @LuisUtrera I could finally fix the problem thanks to your answer. Your answer was correct, but I didn't know what you meant the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it is your `getRegularStyle` and `AppBarTheme` are in different files and they import different package.

e.g.

```
import 'dart:ui';

//Regular Style
TextStyle getRegularStyle({double fontSize = 12, required Color color}){
  return _getTextStyle(fontSize, FontConstants.fontFamily, FontWeightManager.regular, color);
}
```

and

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    centerTitle: true,
    color: ColorManager.primary,
    elevation: AppSize.s4,
    shadowColor: ColorManager.primaryWithOpacity70,
    **titleTextStyle: getRegularStyle(color: ColorManager.white, fontSize: FontSize.s16),**
),
```

One imports `dart.ui`, whereas the other imports `flutter/material.dart` (or other way around). This will cause the argument type cannot be assigned error. Check your import and correct the import if they are different, or paste the complete code files.